# Exception Value: global name 'total_max_counter' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a new table in my MySQL DB with a single field to record an incrementing value. However I keep getting an error:

> Exception Value: global name 'total_max_counter' is not defined

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

**views.py**

```
from survey.models import TotalCounter

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    total_counter = TotalCounter.objects.get_or_create(total_max_counter)
    total_counter.survey_wizard_total += 1 
    total_counter.save()

    for form in form_list:
        form.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

**models.py**

```
class TotalCounter(models.Model):

    total_max_counter = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in `get_or_create()`, you need to specify the argument in the form of `kwargs`. Then only, it will look up an object with the given `kwargs`, creating one if necessary. `kwargs` may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields.

The function definition for `get_or_create()` is:

> get_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)

Secondly, you are trying to update the `survey_wizard_total` field of `TotalCounter` object whereas your model has no such field defined in it. It has only the field `total_max_counter` in it. You will also need to correct that in your code.

This should work for you:

```
from django.db.models import F
from survey.models import TotalCounter

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    total_counter = TotalCounter.objects.get_or_create(total_max_counter__gte=0)[0] 
    total_counter.total_max_counter = F('total_max_counter') + 1 # increment value of `total_max_counter` by 1
    total_counter.save() # save the object

    for form in form_list:
        form.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using get_or_create method in a wrong way:

```
total_counter = TotalCounter.objects.get_or_create(total_max_counter)
```

You are trying to get object from database but you are not making any comparison.
It should be something like:

```
total_counter = TotalCounter.objects.get_or_create(total_max_counter=<some value to match against>)
```

Even after this correction if your query runs, then an object for TotalCounter will be returned which have no attribute '**survey_wizard_total**'

total_counter.**survey_wizard_total** += 1